# Spain visa - must I make entire hotel payment, or is deposit enough?

Tags: visas, spain

I am a Kenyan student studying in the UK. I have a Tier 4 visa. I am applying for a visa to Spain, and one of the requirements is a hotel confirmation.

Do I have to make the full payment for the hotel, or can a deposit from e.g. Hostelworld etc suffice?

Comment: After you book via Hostelworld and pay the deposit, you do have a confirmed booking, so I'd imagine it suffices. No first hand experience though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have read that somewhere too. But I'm hoping for a confirmation from someone who's done it recently, really dont want to end up wasting a lot of money

Comment: I'm with Jonik. If your requirement is a *confirmation*, obviously, you need a *confirmation*, not a paid booking.

Comment: Your question is related to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10532/does-the-hotel-need-to-be-fully-prepaid-before-applying-for-a-swiss-tourist-visa

Comment: Thank you all. I have sent in my application with a booking and deposit. Will update once i hear back from them to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Spain's tourist visa falls under the common European Schengen visa. As with other countries, you do not need to pay for the full hotel booking - just a confirmation email showing a deposit paid on any travel booking site (including Hostelworld) will do just fine.